# Rails form only show future dates in datetime select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a form that I've made using simple_form, one of the fields in the form is a datetime. I'd like to limit it so that users can only select dates that are after the datetime as of now so they can't create records for the past.

I've experimented doing this with validations but I'd just like to limit the form options instead. I limited the hour range to what I wanted but can't find something similar for days.

The form for the event

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>

  <%-# Form input fields -%>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Title' %>
  <%= f.input :event_date, minute_step: 15, start_hour: 7, end_hour: 21 %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' , :class => "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using `datetime_select` for your input?

Comment: I am currently using f.input provided by the simple_form gem but before I was using the datetime_select input.

Comment: And is the front-end requirement that you have a `select` for day, month, year, hour, minute, e.g. using i3 or are you fine with just one dropdown?

Comment: One dropdown would be fine, currently its one dropdown to select the day from the calendar, one for the hour and one for the minute.

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you using a plugin for calendar?

Comment: I've noticed you mentioned datepicker below. You can still use it, just have to parse text to datetime before saving model OR use a library like datetimepicker-rails (https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For Rails 4:**

For rails 4, there is the `date_field` helper which can accept both `min` and `max` values.

You can use this to set the value range wanted. so, you will have something like:

```
<%= f.date_field : event_date, min: Date.today %>
```

You can get more information about this from [the documentation here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-date_field)

**Old answer:**

You can specify the `:start_year` option, as seen on [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001698) here:

> :start_year - Set the start year for the year select. Default is Date.today.year - 5 if you are creating new record. While editing existing record, :start_year defaults to the current selected year minus 5.

So, in this case, what you will have to do is to specify the `:start_year` as the current year.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  what I'm looking for is more like a start_day option but as far as I know that doesn't exist ?

Comment: To do this, you might want to consider using one of the javascript libraries to disable the unwanted date range... e.g. JQuery UI, or even Bootstrap.

Comment: I couldn't manage to find a way of doing this without using a datepicker (from bootstrap or Jquery) which wouldn't work as I've got a datetime field ?

Comment: It so happens that rails-4 got you covered. I've edited my answer with the correct solution for rails-4. Kindly check it out, @Yoklan

Comment: thank you @x6iae - do you know if there is any way to combine f.date_field and a time_field as well?